# Apple's Lightning Cable Pins

Tags: cable

Does anyone know what type of pins Apple use at the end of their lightning cable?

I've seen pins like those but bigger on other products by different companies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see a row of flat connection areas like that on the edge of a circuit board, it's simply called an "edge connector".